# Java program to calculate the number of ways to multiply a given number of matrices

Tags: java, algorithm

I am getting stuck to figure out how to make my program work.  I traced through my code and it does not give me the correct answer!!!! I am trying to solve this without using recursion.

Here is my work so far:

```
    int numberOfWaysToMultiply(int numberOfMatrices){

        in[] myArray = new int[numberOfMatrices];

        int i;  
        myArray[1] = 1;
        myArray[2] = 1;
        int result = 0;

        if(numberOfMatrices >= 3){  
            for( i = 3; i <= numberOfMatrices; i++){    
                result += myArray[i - 1] * myArray[i - 2];
                myArray[i] = result;
            }
        }
        return myArray[numberOfMatrices];

    }
```

Comment: `f(1).f(n-1)` What is the `.` operator supposed to do? According to the sample you provided, `f(2) = f(1).f(2) + f(2).f(1)`. What does that mean?

Comment: I've read this 3 times and I still don't understand what you are trying to do or what is not working right

Comment: I am sorry the operator "." supposes to perform multiplication:       numberOfWays =  f(1)*f(n-1) + f(2)*f(n-2) + f(3)*f(n-3) + ....... + f(n-1)*f(1);;;;   "n" represents the number of matrices

Comment: (1) I don't know if your use of `matrices` is common usage. (2) The first equation `f(n) = ...` looks a lot like function notation. Is `f` supposed to be a function? (3) `f(n)` certainly could mean "f sub n" where `f` is matrix name and `n` is index (subscript). But you talk about "matriCES"--plural. Do you mean "matrix elements"? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: There's no correlation between the `f(n) = ...` equation and your code, is there? If so, explain?

Comment: We all want to help, but what exactly is `f` in the `f(n) = ...` equation? I just read that `n` is the number of matrices. Are the matrices square (i.e., how to know if they CAN be multiplied)? How do the matrices fit into the code you've shown? What might the `n` matrices look like? And there's only one way to multiply and two given matrices. I think some deskwork might help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The same answer as the first one. Just typed 2 minutes longer :)*

Your implementation is simply wrong.
Just check what you are calculating for numberOfMatrices=4.
First, you define an array that is too small to hold the f(n). After

```
int[] myArray = new int[numberOfMatrices];
```

You have an array with 4 Elements. from myArray[0] to myArray[3].
Later in the last iteration of the for loop you will try to set myArray[4].
Let's assume you have corrected this line, and declared

```
int[] myArray = new int[numberOfMatrices+1];
```

Let's iterate through the loop and see what happens.

**Step 1**

> i = 3, result = 0, myArray = [0,1,1,0,0] (don't forget the element with index 0).
>
> result += myArray[1]*myArray[2] => result = 0 + 1*1 => result = 1
>
> myArray[3] = result => myArray[3] = 1

**Step 2**

> i = 4, result = 1, myArray = [0,1,1,1,0]
>
> result += myArray[2]*myArray[3] => result = 1 + 1*1 => result = 2
>
> myArray[4] = result => myArray[4] = 2

So after the last iteration you will have following int array:[0,1,1,1,2]

What you need is following:

```
int[] f = new int[numberOfMatrices+1];
f[1] = 1;
f[2] = 1;

for(int i = 3; i<=numberOfMatrices; i++){
  for(int k=1; k < i; k++){ // k will be max. i-1
    f[i] += f[k]*f[i-k];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I observe.

You have a description of the end result.  You can some random code that does something entirely different.  And you have no idea how to get from where you are to where you need to be.

What you need to do is first solve the problem by hand.  Actually sit down, try to figure out how to get the answer for `f(3)`.  For `f(4)`.  And so on.

When you do that you'll find that you cannot generate `f(n)` until you have `f(1), f(2), ..., f(n-1)`.  And you'll find that generating each one of those requires all of the others.

Try to work out the pattern.  Turn it into comments.  Expand step by step.  So you might start with this:

```
// f(1) = 1
// f(2) = 2
// for n = 3 to numberOfMatrices
//     find f(n)
// return f(numberOfMatrices)
```

And then you expand the `find f(n)` bit.

```
// f(1) = 1
// f(2) = 2
// for n = 3 to numberOfMatrices
//     f(n) = 0
//     for i = 1 to n-1
//         f(n) += f(i) * f(n-i)
// return f(numberOfMatrices)
```

Now you have an algorithm.  Turn each comment into code and you should get your answer.  I won't finish your homework by doing that, but it should be straightforward.  You're storing `f(n)` as `myArray[n]`, etc.

BTW bug warning.  Arrays in Java always start at 0.  So you will need to either have `f(n)` be `myArray[n-1]` or else make `myArray` one larger than you are right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute n! (read: "n factorial" or "the factorial of n")

```
int f = 1;
for(int i = 1; i<=numberOfMatrices; i++){
  f = f * i;
}
return f;
```

Note: this will overflow a Java `int` even for small values of `numberOfMatrices`.

Comment: Seriously? You got that from what he wrote? Is it stated correctly? Is it a common-ish math/CS task?

Comment: No, the question isn't stated clearly at all.  I inferred it from (a) the formula he was giving and (b) the name of the function (the number of ways you can multiple a set of `n` matrices is `n!`, since matrix multiplication is non-commutative.  What gives me pause is that the method was declared as `int`, but he was trying to pass back an array.  So maybe he's really looking for something entirely.

Comment: Oh, criminey. Of COURSE. If you have 6 matrices (or complex numbers) there are 6! ways of multiplying (or doing any other binary operation?).... I feel dense; i.e., normal.